# How can I interpret to a sequence diagram an action from an Analysis Pattern?

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, uml, sequence-diagram

Based on the Accountability Analysis Pattern:

[image]

The concept is that we have a class diagram following the logic of the Accountability Analysis Pattern. How can I use the given function `assignStaffContact()` to assign contact?

I have undrerstood that `StaffContact` class is a control class and the `Client`, `StaffMember` are entity classes (we don't care about the `TimePeriod` class).

I cannot figure out which classes are gonna play a part in the procedure of assigning staff contact in order to create the proper sequence diagram (UML) of this action. Arbitrarily there must be a boundary class providing the wanted interface. The actor is gonna pick the case of assigning staff contact, which will trigger the method `assignStaffContact()` of the control class `StaffContact` but with which entity classes this will communicate and finally assign the staff?

I am getting confused with class `ContactForCampaign` and the logic behind it being connecte to the classes `Client` and `StaffMember`. I hope I explained well enough my problem and my thought process.

Comment: What makes you think that there must be a boundary or a control class?  The model could be a domain model with only entities.

Comment: Based on the fuctionality of the staffContact class and the way it is presented it comparison to the others (with methods controlling the HR), we can safely assume that it is a control class (or at least use it as so). The boundary class like I said its arbitrary and its not shown in the above class diagram, it just helps my thought process going step by step on how someone would proceed to assign staff contact. It can be ignored if it is causing a misunderstanding. Either way somehow I must navigate through this classes to assign staff contact and I am not sure how.

Comment: If your issue is with the operation: it sends a message to `ContactForCampaign` (which is not yet present and should probably called `assignCommisisoner(Client)`). Similarly with Responsible.

Comment: Can you explain the role of `ContactForCampaign`? 1 `Client` corresponds to many `ContactForCampaign`, does this mean that `Client` probably has a data structure (e.g. linkedlist) of them and why?  But yes my main problem is what kind of messages will they exchange.  So after the `assignStaffContact()` you are suggesting that it should call `assignCommissioner(Client)` from the `ContactForCampaign`. Could it aslo call `makeResponsible(StaffMember)` from `ContactForCampaign` in order to create a connection between client and the staffMember?

Comment: in the entity boundary control model, nothing is arbitrary. Control classes correspond to use cases and their implementation, and boudaries correspond to the asociation use case/actor.  Do you know the corresponding use cases to be able to make such a statement? The fact that there are operations is not sufficient, because the same kind of operations can be on any domain model class. Moreover, control classes are rarely associated with domain classes, because they are not  structurally linked, but are only temporarily related ,for the time of the UC execution (use dependency)

Comment: Ok ignore the boundrary and control classes. What is your suggestion on how the classes interact with one another in order to `assignStaffContact()`?

Comment: What shall assignStaffContact do? What are the input and the output?

Answer (score 0):

This diagram says that:

- A `StaffContact` instance can be associated to several `ContactForCampaign` instances
- Each instance of `ContactForCampaign` is associated with exactly one instance of a `Campaign`, and defines exactly one `StaffMember` object as responsible, and. one `Client` object as commissioner (probably for the campaign).

As a consequence, we can only guess that  `StaffContact::assignContact()` requires to know which StaffMember to add (should be an argument of the operation). Since several `ContactForCampaign` instances can be considered, the ooeration would probably also need to know which `ContactForCampaign` is relevant for the assignment. Probably this can be determined with the help of a `Campaign` parameter. Two cases must then be considered: replacing a staff member of an existing `ContactForCampaign` or create a new one if no assignment exist for a campaign. You have now all the ingredients for your sequence diagram. Note also that the operation would need to know which client is to be assigned as commissioner if a new `ContactForCampaign` os created.

The result could look like (simplified):

[image]

Note that `StaffContact::removeStaffContact()` does not seem relevant, in view of the multiplicity 1 for the `StaffMember`, unless you condider removing as well the ContactForCampaign, which would then cause to lose the information regarding the commissioner.

Last but not least, in view of the 1 multiplicity on the side of StaffContact, it would not be a control class, since the control is in princple existing for the time of the use case execution only, and should not have a permanent semantic link to the objects that it controls.